# Does Android SDK logcat show custom Log.d() messages in the same order in which they are created?

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat

I have the following code section inside a Thread

```
    if(isPlaying){
        if(applyDsp){
            // Convert short lin[] to double
             Log.d("MYLOG", "applyDSP is True");

            if(bufferFull){
                // when the code reaches here x[39] always holds the latest sample
                // (if lin.length  == 1)
                Log.d("MYLOG", "bufferFull is True");
                for(i=0;i<(lin.length - 1);i++){
                    x[i] = x[i+1];
                }
            }
```

This is inside an infinite loop inside a Thread. THe Thread's run() function does not end until this infinite loop ends. So the above code section gets keeps on getting called until some other condition is fulfilled elsewhere. `applyDsp` and `bufferFull` are `boolean` variables. They are initially false, but once they become true they are not reset to false within the infinite loop inside the run() function. Once `bufferFull` becomes true, the messages `applyDSP is True` and `bufferFull is True` should be diplayed alternatively everytime the infinite loop executes. But I saw that sometimes the message `applyDSP is True` came continuously multiple times, then the two alternated, then `applyDSP is True` came continuosly again, then they alternated again, and so on. I have looked throught he code many times and cannot find why `bufferFull` would be reset back to false. So I am now guessing that perhaps the messages are not being displayed in the proper order.

Does the Logcat buffer it's messages first before displaying them, or is the order in which they are seen on the Logcat the exact order in which they are created?

---EDIT---
using the method explained in the comments on the answer by @TCA, it only writes a small section of the logcat output to file, probably the one's being generated at the time the command is given. I want the logcat output to be streamed to the file as it is streamed to the logcat panel in the android SDK.

Comment: Are you sure you just have one instance for the Thread, you'd better add this.toString() to your output and watch if there is another instance of the Thread class.

Comment: There is only one instance of the Thread class running (besides the default UI Thread, but I don't think that should cause any problems). If I did have multiple instances of the same Thread class running, it would cause other problems that I would have noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be outputting Log messages in order, if  you have doubt  append

`System.currentTimeMillis()`

With your Log message and check against time.

Like

> Log.d("MYLOG TIME IN MILLSEC:"+System.currentTimeMillis(), "bufferFull
>   is True");

Comment: there are so many messages coming continuously I'm beginning to think if it's just playing tricks on my eyes. Is tere a way to send all the logcat output to a file instead of just the display? And I do not mean clicking on the save button, I want the logcat to be directed towards a file instead of the display.

Comment: Also I just want the log messages from my own app only, and not everything

Comment: $adb logcat -d | grep 'com.yourpakage.name'  > mylog.txt

Comment: is this good for only one program execution session? I don't want to make it permanent, I just want to be able to do it when I need to. If there are some options in the SDK that I could eneble then those would be most helpful and easier for me to understand

Comment: Hey you can find how to use adb here http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCommandLine/article.html#adb_overview

Comment: running your example says grep not found, how do I do this in windows?

Comment: and the linked page does not have any information regarding logcat

Comment: @user13267 if you do not wish to work with the low-level tools there is also `monitor` (should reside in the sdk's tools folder), which provides a filterable logcat view in its graphical user interface.

Comment: what I really need to do is redirect or stream the logcat messages (but only the ones generated by y app) to a file instead f just the display provided in the SDK so that I can look through the long list of messages at my leisure. It look like the logcap panel in the SDK only shows a certain maximum number of messages at any given time, replacing old messages with newer ones.